# Using Hubspot GET Method I want to extract information present inside each campaign_id at a time

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests, hubspot

I have a campaign data am able to fetch list of `campaign_ids` from the hubspot URL but am not getting how to extract information from each `campaign_id` at a time for multiple campaign_ids and store it to a dataframe.

```
{
"campaigns": [
    {
        "id": 2341356301,
        "lastUpdatedTime": 16429283391399,
        "appId": 189891,
        "appName": "sample2"
    },
    {
        "id": 18645336279,
        "lastUpdatedTime": 1684283410207,
        "appId": 36036,
        "appName": "sample1"
    },
    {
        "id": 25529684,
        "lastUpdatedTime": 16429283391399,
        "appId": 272799,
        "appName": "sample"
    }
 ],
"hasMore":true,
 "offset":"ABCDZYW$AKLRD"
 }
```

Now I am trying to extract information tagged inside for id key for all the 3 campaign_ids but am getting 404 Method no response error.

Code which I tried using Python:

```
 api_key= 'pat-na1-2023ghmc-bmc54-gomc38-1899-63yz459a3654'
 campaign_ids = ['2341356301', '18645336279', '25529684']  # Add all your campaign IDs here
 endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/campaigns/{campaign_ids}? 
 hapikey='pat-na1-2023ghmc-bmc54-gomc38-1899-63yz459a3654'
 print("endpoint",endpoint)
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer pat-na1-2023ghmc-bmc54-gomc38-1899-63yz459a3654' }
campaign_data=[]

for campaign_id in campaign_ids:
   print("campaign_id",campaign_id)
   response= requests.get(endpoint.format(campaign_ids=campaign_id),headers=headers)
   print("response",response)
if response.status_code==200:
    campaign_details=response.json()
    campaign_data.append(campaign_details)

else:
    print('Error occurred',campaign_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

We just have to remove the "?" at the end and try. 
`endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/campaigns/{campaign_ids}`